# Area of the intersection of a plane and a solid

Tags: multivariable-calculus, area

I have a solid $$x^2 + z^2 = 1$$ and a plane $$y + z = 2$$ that I need to calculate the area of their intersection. I don't know if I am supposed to use single or double integrals, neither if it's ok to draw the orthogonal projection. This problem seems simple, but I can't figure where is the start line.

Comment: First an English spelling lesson- the word is "plane", not "plan".  The silent e is necessary to get the long a.

Comment: In this case area would be 0? Did you mean $x^2+z^2 \leq 1$?

Comment: Have you tried to understand how the intersection looks like?

Comment: @RahulMadhavan it's the area of the plane inside the solid.

Comment: @John117 yeah, but since x, y and z variate I don't know where shall i begin.

Comment: Do you know the area of the circle $x^2+z^2 \leq 1$ (projection of the intersection in $XZ$ plane)? Now use the normal vector to the plane to multiply by a factor to find the surface area. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve this.  The simplest is if you recognize that your solid is an infinite cylinder, and the plane is slicing it at a $\pi/4$ angle. So the result is an ellipse, and its area will be the area of the circle scaled up by a factor of $\frac{1}{\cos \pi/4}$.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use integral, then:

$\begin{cases}x^2+z^2=1\rightarrow y=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}\\y+z=2\rightarrow z=2-y\rightarrow tan(\alpha)=-1\rightarrow |\alpha|= 45^o\rightarrow cos 45^o=\frac 1{\sqrt 2}\end{cases}$

$$A=4\int^1_0dx\int^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}_0dy$$

$$A=4\sqrt 2\int^1_0(\sqrt{1-x^2})dx=4\sqrt 2\big[\frac x2\sqrt{1-x^2}+\frac 12 sin^{-1 }\frac x1\big]^1_0=4\sqrt2(\frac12\times\frac{\pi}2)=\sqrt 2 \pi$$

Note: $\int\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx=\frac x2\sqrt{a^2-x^2}+\frac{a^2}2 sin^{-1}\frac xa$

Comment: Sorry if I'm mistaken, but using the method provided by the other answer, I get $\sqrt{2}*\pi$. Now I'm not sure which of these are right.

Comment: @ShinYousoro, that is correct for when the equation of plane is $y=z$, where in your question it  is $y+z=2$

Comment: I'm trying to follow what you did here, and I don't know where your integral is coming from.  We're trying to find the area of the ellipse, which is sloped at 45º.  We aren't getting the volume.  Adding a constant to the height should have no effect.  Moving the ellipse vertically doesn't change its area.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor, You are right mate. I corrected my answer.